# Маска ввода textbox для телефона WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, inputmask

У меня есть textbox в который из бд выводится номер телефона:

**XAML:**

```
<Label Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.Column="0"
       Content="Номер телефона" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="1"
         MaxLength="64"
         Text="{Binding Phone,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                        NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

**MODEL:**

```
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Мне нужно что бы при вводе в это поле вместо +375291234567 вводилось +375(29)123-45-67 для Белоруссии либо вместо +78001234567 вводилось +7(800)123-45-67 для России. Как реализовать такую маску для одного текстового поля?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [`WPF Toolkit`](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit), у них есть [`MaskedTextBox`](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MaskedTextBox)

Comment: @АндрейNOP там можно сделать на одно поле несколько масок?

Comment: Делайте смену маски в зависимости от страны

Comment: @АндрейNOP не подходит, есть еще какие либо решения?

Comment: Может у кого-нибудь есть, подождем ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал следующим образом: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ Правильное форматирование TextBox WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869367/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-textbox-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать ToString с перегрузкой для формата:

```
(88005553535).ToString("+#-###-###-##-##") => +8-800-555-35-35
```

Для России.
Если нужно для нескольких стран, то можно подготовить Dictionary с вариантами для разных стран:

```
enum Country
{
    Ru,
    Blr
}

static Dictionary<Country, string> Mask = new Dictionary<Country, string>
{
    [Country.Ru] = "+#-###-###-##-##",
    [Country.Blr] = "+###(##)###-##-##"
};

Console.WriteLine((375291234567).ToString(Mask[Country.Blr])); // => +375(29)123-45-67
Console.WriteLine((88005553535).ToString(Mask[Country.Ru])); // => +8-800-555-35-35
```

Прошу обратить внимание, что для перегрузки ToString с форматом необходимо, чтобы поле Phone было типа int.

Comment: 375291234567 в int не поместится

Comment: используйте long, uint, ulong, в чем проблема