# Правильное форматирование TextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, регулярные-выражения, mask

В общем мне нужно создать маску ввода для телефона, формат: +375(29)123-45-67.
Я сделал следующим способом, но выглядит это ужасно и при вводе/удалении в этом куча недочетов, как можно это сделать по другому не используя сторонний [Toolkit MaskedTextBox](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MaskedTextBox) ?

**.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Номер телефона:" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
             Text="{Binding Phone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             MinWidth="150" MaxLength="{Binding MaxLength}"/>
</Grid>
```

**.cs:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _phone;

    public MyClass()
    {
        MaxLength = 17;
    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get => _phone;
        set
        {
            if (value == _phone) return;
            _phone = value;
            PhoneMask();
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Phone);
        }
    }

    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    public async Task PhoneMask()
    {
        char[] charsToTrim = { '+', '(', ')', '-', ' '};
        var newVal = Phone.Trim(charsToTrim);

        switch (newVal.Length)
        {
            case 3:
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{3})", "+$1");
                break;
            case 5:
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{3})(\d{2})", "+$1($2)");
                break;
            case 10:
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{3})(.{1})(\d{2})(.{1})(\d{3})",
                                     "+$1$2$3$4$5");
                break;
            case 12:
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{3})(.{1})(\d{2})(.{1})(\d{3})(\d{2})",
                                     "+$1$2$3$4$5-$6-");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я же давал вам развернутый ответ под ваш другой, точно такой же вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867026/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-textbox-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-wpf/867082#867082

Comment: @LiptonDev ваш способ не подходит для конкретно этой задачи. Там также большие недочеты: при вводе цифр форматирование начинается с самого конца +###(##)###-##-#3, +###(##)###-##-37, +###(##)###-#3-75 и т.д. Такой вариант отображения при начальном вводе не подходит

Comment: https://www.xamarinhelp.com/masked-entry-in-xamarin-forms/ есть и такой вариант решения проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделал таким образом, теперь все отлично работает без ошибок:

**.cs:**

```
public int PhoneLength { get; set; }

public async Task PhoneMask()
{
    var newVal = Regex.Replace(Phone, @"[^0-9]", "");
    if (PhoneLength != newVal.Length && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(newVal))
    {
        PhoneLength = newVal.Length;
        Phone = string.Empty;
        if (Region == "BY")
        {
            if (newVal.Length <= 3)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{3})", "+$1");
            }
            else if (newVal.Length <= 5)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{3})(\d{0,2})", "+$1($2)");
            }
            else if (newVal.Length <= 8)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{0,3})", "+$1($2)$3");
            }
            else if (newVal.Length <= 10)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})", "+$1($2)$3-$4");
            }
            else if (newVal.Length > 10)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})", "+$1($2)$3-$4-$5");
            }
        }
        else if (Region == "RU")
        {
            if (newVal.Length <= 1)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{1})", "+$1");
            }
            else if (newVal.Length <= 4)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{1})(\d{0,3})", "+$1($2)");
            }
            else if (newVal.Length <= 7)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{0,3})", "+$1($2)$3");
            }
            else if (newVal.Length <= 9)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})", "+$1($2)$3-$4");
            }
            else if (newVal.Length > 9)
            {
                Phone = Regex.Replace(newVal, @"(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})", "+$1($2)$3-$4-$5");
            }
        }
    }
}
```